# Convert String To Object-Variable-Name?

Tags: php, string, variables

i want to turn a simple string like that "response->dict->words" into a variable name that i can actually work with. I will give an example now. Lets assume the value of `$response->dict->words is 67`.

Example:

```
$var = "response->dict->words"

echo $$var; /* PRINT THE VALUE 67 FROM $response->dict->words*/
```

As you may notice i put an extra dollar sign before the $var because this should work, but it doesn't.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Here you should use `eval()` instead of variable variables or something like that, but you'd better restructure your logic. There should be no need to make a string -> object call.

Answer (score 5):

```
class ClassOne {
    public function test() {
        return 'test';
    }
}

class ClassTwo {
    public function test2() {
        return 'test2';
    }
}

$one = new ClassOne();
$two = new ClassTwo();

$objects = array('one', 'two');
$methods = array('test', 'test2');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($objects); $i++) {
    echo ${$objects[$i]}->$methods[$i]();
}
```

You can store classnames or method names as strings and later use them, or even store variable names, like here `${$objects}` (variable variables), but you cannot store whole logic.

To evaluate whole logic, you have to use `eval()`, which is most probably bad idea

```
$var = "response->dict->words"
eval("?> <?php echo $".$var.";");
```

You can split your string and make the call as below:

```
class Response {
    public $dict;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->dict = new stdClass();
        $this->dict->words = 'words test';
    }
}

$response = new Response();

$var = 'response->dict->words';

$elements = explode('->', $var);

echo ${$elements[0]}->$elements[1]->$elements[2];
```

Results into `words test`

Or, if you don't know the level of nesting the object call, you can perform the call in a foreach loop. When the loop exits, the last call will be available after it:

```
class Response {
    public $dict;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->dict = new stdClass();
        $this->dict->words = new stdClass();
        $this->dict->words->final = 'test chained string';
    }
}

$response = new Response();

$var = 'response->dict->words->final';

$elements = explode('->', $var);

foreach ($elements as $key => $element) {
    if ($key == 0) {
        $call = ${$element};
        continue;
    }
    $call = $call->$element;
}

echo $call;
```

Results into: `test chained string`

Comment: i still didnt get the use of $call = $call->$element

Answer (score -4):

There is a better way, why don't you cache the variable like

```
     $var = $response->dict->words;
```

Comment: because he does not have a variable, but a string