# How to calling dynamic methods in php?

Tags: php

I want to calling property `$property` with `$method` similar this code :

```
class test
{
    public $property= 5;
    public function method()
    {
        return $this;
    }
}

$text = 'method().property';
$array = explode('.', $text);
$tt = implode('->', $array);
$object = new test;
echo $object->$tt;
```

but this error returned :

> Notice: Undefined property: test::$method()->property in
>   /var/www/html/test2.php on line 16

How can I fix it?

Comment: By not doing two things at the same time. Choose what you want to do: call method or read property

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24957587/convert-string-to-object-variable-name/24957760#24957760

Comment: Replace your last line with `echo eval('return $object->' . $tt . ';');`

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated? I think your looking more for something like this. Otherwise please let me know an explain more what you want:

```
<?php

    class test {
        public $property = 5;

        public function method() {
            return $this->property;
        }


    }

    $object = new test;
    echo $object->method();

?>
```

Output:

```
5
```

Comment: Well, if u say 'why so complicated' ==> `echo $object->property;`  since its public :)

Comment: @DarkBee Jeah you're right! But i think OP wants to call a property with a function so i have still a function in the answer

Comment: Well, maybe the OP's purpose is to parses a string in some format and create instances, invoke methods, reach properties

Comment: True that. Guess OP needs to read about getters/setters though

Comment: I want to get `method's` name and `property's name` from user!

Comment: @behzad see my comment in your original post. I have already answered similar question with several way to do it

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here. Your method name string comes with parentheses. Thus, invocation like stringified method will not work.

Let's say you have `$method = 'myMethod()';` if you try `$obj->$method();` it will scream for undefined method called `myMethod()()`. If you leave it `$obj->$method` it will not find a property with this name.

Your simpliest solution is to get rid from the parentheses with some predefined logic (because later, you might need arguments, eh?);

First solution... just remove them...:

```
class test
{
    public $property= 5;
    public function method()
    {
        return $this;
    }
}

$text = 'method().property';
$array = explode('.', $text);
$array[0] = str_replace("()", "", $array[0]);

$test = new test();
echo $test->$array[0]()->$array[1];
```

Here the output is `5`.

However, I guess you might expect from the user `method(arg1, arg2).property`. Then:

```
class test
{
    public $property= 5;
    public function method($a, $b)
    {
        $argsProduct = $a*$b;
        $this->property += $argsProduct;
        return $this;
    }
}

$text = 'method(2, 6).property';
$array = explode('.', $text);

$array[0] = str_replace(["(", ")", ","], " ", $array[0]);
$array[0] = preg_split("/\\s+/", $array[0]);

$args = array_slice($array[0], 1, count($array[0])-1, true);

$test = new test();
echo call_user_func_array(array($test, $array[0][0]), $args)->$array[1];
```

Output: `17; // 2 * 6 = 12; 12 + 5 = 17`

Ofcourse there might be better solution to extract the arguments, but it's not on my mind right now. What is important to know is that you need to know the predefined structure which the user can send you as a string. And, obligatory, TO NOT USE EVAL :) If you really need a chain object call sent as a string from the user, it's justified to write your own string parser for that (like the mini version above).

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
class test
{
  public $property= 5;
  public function method()
  {
    return $this->property;
  }
}

$object = new test;
$text = $object->method();
$array = explode('.', $text);
$tt = implode('->', $array);
print_r($tt);
```